# Why does this Theano code run successfully without any errors?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, deep-learning

I have the following piece of code borrowed from an online tutorial. I see that the below line written in the main method of the code

```
c = broadcasted_add(a, b)
```

is adding the tensor 'a' of dimension (2,1,2,2) and tensor 'b' of dimension (2,2,2,2). How is it able to add correctly even when we have declared broadcastable as 'false' in the make_tensor method? Shouldn't we declare broadcastable as True so it can add with different dimensions? Shouldn't it throw an error saying dimensions don't match? Is my understanding of broadcastable wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from theano import function
import theano.tensor as T

def make_tensor(dim):
    """
    Returns a new Theano tensor with no broadcastable dimensions.
    dim: the total number of dimensions of the tensor.
    """

    return T.TensorType(broadcastable=tuple([False] * dim), dtype='float32')()

def broadcasted_add(a, b):
    """
    a: a 3D theano tensor
    b: a 4D theano tensor
    Returns c, a 4D theano tensor, where
    c[i, j, k, l] = a[l, k, i] + b[i, j, k, l]
    for all i, j, k, l
    """

return a.dimshuffle(2, 'x', 1, 0) + b

def partial_max(a):
    """
    a: a 4D theano tensor
    Returns b, a theano matrix, where
    b[i, j] = max_{k,l} a[i, k, l, j]
    for all i, j
    """

return a.max(axis=(1, 2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = make_tensor(3)
    b = make_tensor(4)
    c = broadcasted_add(a, b)
    d = partial_max(c)

    f = function([a, b,], d)

    rng = np.random.RandomState([1, 2, 3])
    a_value = rng.randn(2, 2, 2).astype(a.dtype)
    b_value = rng.rand(2, 2, 2, 2).astype(b.dtype)
    c_value = np.transpose(a_value, (2, 1, 0))[:, None, :, :] + b_value
    expected = c_value.max(axis=1).max(axis=1)

    actual = f(a_value, b_value)

    assert np.allclose(actual, expected), (actual, expected)
    print "SUCCESS!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works is that new dimensions added by `dimshuffle` via the `'x'` parameter value are always broadcastable.

Notice that in `broadcasted_add` the only dimension that needs to be broadcasted is the dimension that was added to `a` via the `dimshuffle`. None of the other dimensions need to be broadcasted.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the simple explanation